# How to show role-specific version of EditForm.aspx?

Tags: 2010, designer-workflow, custom-form

is there a way to show different versions of EditForm.aspx, depending on who wants to edit the item, by using workflows only (as I have no access to the server and can't deploy any solutions)?

The scenario is as follows: I try to create an issue tracking system which includes several roles, each having different responsibilities and therefore needing to edit different columns in a list item. The creator of an item needs to be able to edit his entries (mainly title and description), a coordinator needs to assign other people (and blocks the creator from any further edits by editing the item himself), a validator needs to edit other data and so on. The role a user has is determined by columns in the item (e.g. the validator is assigned as such by the coordinator with a people picker).

It's required that each role can only view and edit specific parts of the item, so I somehow need to find out who is trying to edit the item in order to determine his role and display the applicable version of EditForm.aspx.

Is there any way to accomplish that without coding? I can only use the SP Designer and the browser-version of the page, so third-party-solutions or own coded solutions can't be used..

Thanks in advance!

edit: if anyone has any advice on how to accomplish the abovementioned with InfoPath forms, feel free to help ;) (as I have even less experience with InfoPath than with SharePoint..)

Comment: I can't imagine how that should work by using workflows. Is it possible for you to use an InfoPath Form for this?

Comment: If I can achieve this with InfoPath Forms I'll definitely try. Unfortunately I'm not very experienced with SharePoint, and I can only try solutions that don't require any access to the server itself.. So if InfoPath is still an option, I'll start working on it :)

Comment: you don't need access to the server itself but you need the rights to publish the form, if you don't have them then this is no option

Comment: I'm quite sure I have these rights to publish forms, so I guess I'll have a look into it, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an InfoPath Form and Show/Hide certain fields when comparing this list field (ex. validator) with the logged in user.
I guess this is the hard part, so I did some research for you, it's about accessing the currently logged in user:

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/Pages/How-to-set-Current-User-Name-to-InfoPath-Person-Group-Picker.aspx

let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Hi again, is there any way to check if the user opening the form is a member in a specific sharepoint group? Again I found only third-party solutions to achieve that..